# Structure and tagged union in c

Tags: c, struct, udp, unions, udpclient

```
#define HOST_NAME "UDP"
#define ADDRESS "127.0.0.1" 
struct UDP_IP_Parameters { 
        uint version; /* e.g. "1.0" = 0x0100 */
        uint port; /* PORT */
        taggedunion {
            "HOST_NAME" char[256];
            "ADDRESS" char[15];
        };
};

int main()
{
struct UDP_IP_Parameters udp;
udp.version = 0x0100;
udp.port = 444;

}
```

I have created a structure and taggedunion nested within that. Is it possible to define the host name and address as constant like above ?? Is it possible to assign some values by creating a objects for it. Could anyone give me some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

That is not C.

No, you can't specify values inside a type declaration.

The closest you can do is probably something like:

```
typedef struct {
  uint16_t version; /* Guessing size requirements. */
  uint16_t port;
  bool resolved;
  union {
    char host_name[256];
    char address[24];
  } addr;
} UDP_IP_Parameters;
```

The above uses the `resolved` flag to "tag" the union, so the program can know which member of the union is valid.

You should be able to initialize an instance like so:

```
UDP_IP_Parameters so = { 0x100, 80, false, { "stackoverflow.com" } };
```

Not sure if (in C99) you can use the dotted syntax to do this:

```
UDP_IP_Parameters so = { 0x100, 80, true, { .address = "198.252.206.16" } };
```

Comment: is it possible to use bool ?? I am getting error as : syntax erro : identifier bool .

Comment: @user2984410 `bool` is a standard type since C99, but you need to `#include <stdbool.h>`. If you're using a non-C99 compiler (such as Visual Studio), it won't work.

Comment: I include stdbool.h then also I am getting error like :fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdbool.h': No such file or directory