# How to form the logic to solve differential equations using Euler's method in C

Tags: c, differential-equations

We have the following mathematical formulas to solve differential equations by Euler's method

*x<sub>n+1</sub> = x<sub>n</sub> + h*

y<sub>n+1</sub> = y<sub>n</sub> + h*f(x<sub>n</sub>, y<sub>n</sub>)

Suppose we have been provided y(x<sub>0</sub>)=any value,then we have x<sub>0</sub> and y<sub>0</sub> and also h has been provided by the user.

I am having problem to understand how can I accept the function f(x<sub>n</sub>, y<sub>n</sub>) from the user since the function can be either algebraic,trigonometric,exponential or logarithmic and the function would be of type dy/dx=(expression).The program code should be able to solve any differential expression entered by the user and the answers of the approximations must be correct upto 4 decimal places.

It is possible to accept the expression as a String but I would not be able to perform calculations on String.Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.

Site of Euler's method:http://calculuslab.deltacollege.edu/ODE/7-C-1/7-C-1-h-c.html

**Example Input:**

expression input:

dy/dx=x+2y

initial conditions input:

x<sub>0</sub>=0, y<sub>0</sub>=0

enter step size: h=0.25

enter the value for which you want to find solution for: x=1

**Example output:**

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f1sv.png)

Comment: Reading mathematical functions from input and then having them evaluated is not trivial. You should probably try to find a library to do that.

Comment: So you want an expression evaluator? There is no such thing in standard C. You can write one or find some source code on the web, but it's a rather challenging thing for a beginner.

Comment: Please try to clarify by giving examples of input and output. How do several typical inputs look like? Your question as it is sounds like you refer to a string with the math expression of the function (in that case see above comments). But maybe there is an implemented function like `double inputfunction(double x)`? and you could take a pointer to it....

Comment: You will have to take the input as a string, otherwise there would be no way to preserve (e.g. `sin(3*x)`, etc..). As mentioned parsing expressions/equations is not trivial, but can be done. Have a look at [How to parse a formula from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450479/how-to-parse-a-formula-from-a-string)

Comment: And if you go to the length of using an expression parser/evaluator, you might want to use the classical Runge-Kutta 4th order method. With Euler you need step size h=1e-5 or smaller to reach your precision goal, with RK4 a step size h=0.01 should be sufficient. This materially reduces the number of function (parse tree) evaluations and thus the execution time.

Comment: "how can I accept the function ...either algebraic,trigonometric,exponential or logarithmic" --> than ask the user if "algebraic,trigonometric,exponential or logarithmic" is desired, then ask for co-efficients.